# How would you convert an ObjectID of mongodb to an object in order to store inside an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, mongodb, object

How would you convert an objectID of a MongoDB entry into an object so that you can store it in an array?

Having searched all over the internet, I resorted here as my one last option.

What I want to achieve is, storing IDs into an array. Those IDs are strings. They needed to be converted into objects, if they are to be stored.

How would you do that?

Following is a small snippet of the code for your review:

```
 var user_id_object = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user_id));
    console.log((user_id_object));
    console.log(typeof (user_id_object));
```

Here' s what I get in the console:

```
Your server is running on the port number 8080
Connected to the MongoDB
5ee9ce5ded28da51fc4072c8
string
Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object, got 5ee9ce5ded28da51fc4072c8
```

What do you think?

Thanks a TON!!

EDIT 1: Got the below error after implementing the Arjun's code:

[image]

Comment: Check the methods on ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;

Comment: I tried it, but didn't help

Answer (score 1):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ID_OF_24_CHARACTERS = '5c6bf11473e216001afa5608' // example
const arrayOfObjectIds = []
if (mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(ID_OF_24_CHARACTERS)) { // validate ObjectId
    const id = mongoose.Type.ObjectId(ID_OF_24_CHARACTERS) // converting string to an ObjectId
    arrayOfObjectIds.push(id)
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this further? Where do you convert the string to an object?

Comment: on the fifth line from the top, added the comment as well

Comment: Your server is running on the port number 8080
Connected to the MongoDB
Cannot read property 'isValid' of undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220355/discussion-between-arjun-singh-and-on-the-way-to-success).